# How to use absolute symbols in position independent code

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, symbols, objcopy

I created an elf file using the following commend:

```
 objcopy -F elf64-x86-64 -B i386 -I binary binary_file output_file.o
```

The elf has 3 absolute symbols (binary_start, binray_end, binary_size)

I tried to compile this elf into a shared library.

The probelm is that I can't reach the size_symbol and the end_symbol when I'm using -fpic (The addresses of the symbols are wrong).

so, what is the proper way to use this kind of symbols in position independent code?

Comment: Why objcopy? Can you show the full compilation commands you've used?

Comment: gcc -shared -fpic -fno-stack-protector

Comment: @Jah How do you know and determine that the addresses are wrong ?

Comment: @nos I'm debbuging it using gdb + I know that absulte symbols points to addresses and not to data (symbol that contains the value for ex. 0xcafecafe will points to the address 0xcafecafe and not to Memory cell that contains the value 0xcafecafe)

Comment: @Jah Ok, but that doesn't answer anything. Which specific address do you see ? Why is that address wrong ? Which address do you expect to see ? (And is your output_file.o linked into the executable directly or do you use some other means of e.g. dynamically loading it ?)